# [python pandas]Is that possible to set style permanently?

Tags: pandas

Via modify pandas files?
Something like change set default style?
Display Maximum columns and rows. Highlights na value as red etc.
I don’t

Answer (score 0):

Use these pandas set options to display more or less rows/columns.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Actually I’m trying to  make this change as default setting.i don’t want to key in these words in the future

Comment: The pandas options are provided for global effect, i.e. within a module or a jupyter notebook, but you have to set them with a script. The best you can probably get away with is: `import pandas as pd`, `import myscript_settings`, where you make any configuration changes in a single file and then just need to import it once per session.